# Using more than 1 css style in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So, before I run completely out of hair, I figured I would reach out for some help from group.  I currently have a site in wordpress that each page needs to have its own css style since no one page has the same style.  How an where in the world do I call for a specific page to only load the style from the specifc css file designed for that page?  I guess I should add that all 10 pages use the header file only with the get_header everything else is styled in very different ways that dont seem to want to work at all with the style.css overriding it or something.

THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP.  AS IT TURNS OUT, I HAVE BEEN STUCK ON STUPID FOR FAR TOO LONG ON THIS ISSUE.  Not sleeping but a few hours a night is a bad time to work on websites.  I have figured things out finally.  All because of your help.

THank you all again for sharing your knowledge...  :)

Comment: Just to update this question about further,  I have tried using the following but it keeps giving me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\FMVConnect Demo\header.php on line 36                                                                                           <?php (is_page_template('methodology.php')) { ?>
  <link href="<?php blog_info('template_url').'/css/method.css'; ?>" rel="stylesheet" />

<?php } ?>

Comment: The usual way to do conditional styling in WP is to use the [body class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) for additional page specific styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the if [is_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

in your header.php where your styles is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"/>
<?php if(is_page( 'YOUR_PAGE' )){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR_OTHER_CSS_LOCATION"/>'; 
}
```

etc. do for each page **YOUR_PAGE** should be your page slug

In your case:

```
<?php if(is_page( 'methodology' )){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/method.css"/>'; 
    }
```

Comment: when you say YOU_PAGE do you mean h t t p ://localhost/methodology/ or the template page name?

Comment: this is what I put in and it did get rid of the style.css but it doesnt seem to be using the directed css style...<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"/>
<?php if(is_page('methodology')){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/method.css"/>'; 
} ?>

Comment: you need to set the full url in the `href` -  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/method.css"/>`

Comment: Og good grief - this just gets more confusing for me.  :)  Your instructions are perfect!  But it only works when I load the info in the index.php file and then it only allows the text style and no other css style to show through....  I have never had this much issues doing a WP site before.  What in the world could I be missing, there has to be something in another file that is throwing this all off.

Comment: what do you mean? put it in your header.php

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark, I finally found the errors throwing everything off.  Your instructions worked perfect when I fixed a few very obvious (now anyway) issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your stylesheet file through [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action of wordpress, in there you can separate your stylesheet files for each page easily. Use [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) function to add stylesheet file and use [`is_page_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) to detect which page you want to include it. I have a sample here

```
<?php 

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rb_enqueue_scripts');
    function rb_enqueue_scripts() {
        if( is_page_template('about.php') ) { //check your page
            wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-about-style', 'http://link-to-your-style-file.css' );
        }

    }
?>
```

You can replace [`is_page_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) by [`is_page($page_id)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) if you have special ID of each page.

Hope this help! :)

Comment: Is there anyway you can provide a bit more details for me on this one?  Im guessing this goes in the header.php like the rest BUT the http:// part is where my question is.  my css file is located in the css file in wordpress so im not sure how to apply the http part or do I really just list the file location in there?

Comment: you can put this code into your theme functions.php file, and to get your css file location, you can use [get_template_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) or [get_stylesheet_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in header.php file

```
<?php 
if(is_page( 'PAGE NAME' ))
{
   echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/css-file-name"/>'; 
}
?>
```